# Reusing a uiview created from a nib in multiple viewcontrollers

Tags: iphone, view, nib, reusability, viewcontroller

OK, sorry, In a nutshell: What is the best/easiest/recommended way of reusing a view created from a nib in multiple viewcontrollers that are also created from nibs?

Comment: question is confusing make it in points so easy to understand and answer

Answer (score 0):

Use the `- (NSArray *)loadNibNamed:(NSString *)name owner:(id)owner options:(NSDictionary *)options` method of `NSBundle` to load your nib.

- Create a nib file and set the File's owner to one of your view controllers. It shouldn't matter which one as long as all the relevant properties are present in both.
- Set up the nib, linking your views/buttons/etc. to the file's owner properties.

In your view controllers do the following

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *myView;
// Add whatever other outlets you need for your nib.

@end

@implementation MyViewController

@synthesize myView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // You set up your other views/ivars/etc. here

    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomView" owner:self options:nil];
    // Assuming that your bundle contains a single top-level object that is linked to the
    //  'myView' property in your view controller, everything should be properly retained
}

@end
```